# Which event does Feathers Authentication return after authenticating user login

Tags: authentication, postman, feathersjs

I am learning Feathers. I try to understand which event a server side Feathers Authentication module sends back to the client after it authenticates the user login information injected from the client (the connection is through socket.io).

Here is the background and the set up:

I created a copy of the example 'feathers-chat' app (https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat) in the Guides on https://docs.feathersjs.com. The app works fine. I can login user at localhost:3030 from a browser. In the browser developer tools, I can see the websocket connection established by socket.io. Inside that connection, there are two events after clicking the login button in the browser:

The first event was sent from the browser to the server:
0: "create"
1: "authentication"
2: { strategy: "local", email: "user_email", password: "user_password" }
3: {}

I assume that the event name of this one is "create" and the rest information in 1-3 are event data.

The second event was sent by the server to the browser after login success:
0: null
1: { accessToken: "token...",
authentication: { strategy: "local", accessToken: "token...",payload: {...} },
user: {...}}

My question is: What is the event name of the second event? Is it null?

The reason for this question is that I try to use Postman to send and receive socket.io event data directly to the server during development. Postman needs a name for its event listener. I can send the first "create" event from Postman to the server successfully (the event was captured in the debugger on the server). But I can't figure out how to capture the second return event from the server in Postman. I created a listener called "null" but it doesn't work.

Comment: I figured it out. No events are sent back. The server sends back an acknowledgement message after receiving the 'create' event for authentication. In Postman, there is a checkbox "Acknowledgement" next to the send event input box. I checked this box and sent the 'create' event for authentication as before. Then I saw a message sent back from the server. It is labelled a 'create' event with two arguments: the first one is null, the second one has the access token and the authentication data as I saw in the browser development tools.

Comment: Please write an answer for your question. Don't use the comments as they can get removed without warning.